# Angular could not be found on the page with angular application while running test for angular app in iFrame

Tags: protractor

I have an angular application running inside iFrame. I must need to launch parent application URL as it provide some flag which makes angular app working as expected. Now I need to write protractor tests for angular app in iFrame.

Here is the code.

```
describe('French page', function() {
var IFRAME = "iframe",
TITLE_FR = 'Découverte automatique',
PAGE_URL = '/SAAS/admin/app/page',
pagePaths = browser.params.paths;;

beforeEach(function (done) {
    LOGIN_PAGE.goToPageAndLogin().then(function (){
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.get(PAGE_URL); // application has angular app in iFrame
        browser.sleep(5000);
        browser.waitForAngular();
        done();
   });
});

afterEach(function (done) {
    demoPause();
    LOGIN_PAGE.logout().then(done);
});

it('should be able to launch with fr-FR locale', function (done) {
    browser.driver.switchTo().frame(IFRAME); //Switch to angular app in   iFrame

   // Check if element text is in french
    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.app-menu li:nth-child(1)  p')).then(function (elem) {
        elem.getText().then(function (text) {
            expect(text).toBe(TITLE_FR); // I can see that both texts are same here while debugging
            browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            done();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

**The test condition passed but it exit with below error.**
Message:

> Failed: Angular could not be found on the page
>   https://host/abcd/admin/app/page

retries looking for angular exceeded

Answer (score 1):

The issue got fixed by putting

**browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;**

before
        browser.get(PAGE_URL);

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. The parameter **IFRAME** passed into:
   `browser.driver.switchTo().frame(IFRAME);` needs to be the **ID**
   property of the element, not the tag name of the element, example:

   **your iframe element**

   `<iframe id="myIframeId" name="frame3">...</iframe>`

   **you would in this case do**

   `browser.diver.switchTo().frame("myIframeId");`
2. Don't call `browser.waitForAngular();` on a non-angular page. Since only your iframe element is Angular, I suggest doing the following to make sure a specific element is present before continuing:

   `browser.driver.wait(function() {
   return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.css("your_selector")).then(function(present) {
       return present;
   });
   }, 20000);`

   This will wait for an element to be present for 20 seconds, regardless of the page being Angular or not and then continue.
3. After you switch to the iframe element, you should call `browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = false;` to turn on Angular synchronization back on. Since your code inside your iframe is Angular.